# 〜など as a more formal version of 〜なんて

Tags: words, particle-など

“〜など” is often explained as introducing vagueness such as, say “本当の自由などない” for “There is no such thing as true freedom.” whereas “〜なんて” is typically first explained as expressing scorn and strong emotion or wonder and secondarily as also introducing vagueness but “〜など” is also often explained as a more formal version of “〜なんて”.

In particular, “〜なんて” is often put behind sentences to express disbelief, surprise or wonder such as “死んだなんて信じられない” to invoke something similar  “I can't believe he actually died.” This sense of “〜なんて” seems to express no vagueness whatsoever and purely wonder or disbelief. In one particular title I'm reading I'm seeing a similar pattern with “〜など” a lot too. Since the characters in it are 1800s European royalty, they speak in very posh Japanese and for instance say “私を捨てて、他の男と一緒になるなど許さない。”.

Is this sense of “〜など” too essentially synonymous with if there would be “〜なんて” there, expressing shock and disbelief or does it still introduce the vagueness and thus means “I will not allow her to do such a thing as casting me away to be with another man.” or is it similar to something like “I will not allow her to actually cast me away to be with another man.”

And other than that, to what extend is “〜など” purely a more formal synonym of “〜なんて”?　Would it for instance also be natural to say something like “私など好きになったなど信じられない。”? or “あなたの恋人になど興味がない。案ずるな。”?

Answer (score 2):

なんて/など (in that usage) always mean *such a thing as*.

The emotional sense like disbelief just comes from the verb.

- 彼女が死んだなんて/など信じられない

Both literally mean *I can't believe such a thing that she died*. Using *actually* is more a matter of translating the disbelief into English.

So 私を捨てて、他の男と一緒になるなど許さない means *I wouldn't allow (such a thing as) you leave me and get together with someone else* - Here using 'such a thing' would be clumsy and require a different word for a proper translation (maybe just *I would NEVER..*).

---

For the last question, you can infer from the [大辞泉 definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9/#jn-164368):

> １ **一例を挙げ**、あるいは、いくつか並べたものを総括して示し、それに限らず、ほかにも同種類のものがあるという意を表す。**…なんか**。「赤や黄—の落ち葉」「寒くなったのでこたつを出し—する」
>
> ２ ある事物を**例示し、特にそれを軽んじて扱う**意を表す。否定的な表現の中で多く使われる。**…なんか。…なんて。**「わたしのこと—お忘れでしょう」「金—いるものか」

Both mean adding example, but the #2 connotes dismissing feeling of the speaker and なんて is only listed there. That said, both are similar and whether or not なんて can replace など is a matter of context (and syntax<sup>1</sup>).

<sup>1</sup> 赤や黄なんての葉 is simply ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't think that's true given that “なんて” is very often used even without an extra verb to signify disbelief. “死んだなんて” can be used on it's own to express a nuance similar to “To think he died...” or something like that. I do not believe that the “disbelief” sense is necessarily purely covered by “信じられない”. I have never seen something like “死んだなど” as a standalone utterance though while say “浮気したなんて。” as a standalone utterance is quite common. “興味なんてない！” also doesn't really mean “I don't have such a thing as interest.” either I feel. It simply means “I have no bloody interest” and emphasizes it.

Comment: Otherwise, I will say that that dictionary you came with is most helpful. It does seem to express that sense 2 is possible with “〜など” too while only listing “なんて” and “なんか” as examples.

Comment: @Zorf If you think なんて itself has the disbelief sense and など doesn't, it's simply false. 彼が死んだなど信じられない is as valid as 彼が死んだなんて信じられない. You see the latter often just because it's more colloquial and sentences ending in なんて may be more frequent because omission fits better with colloquialism.

Comment: I made this topic because I wanted to know whether “〜など” had the same disbelief sense. I know “〜なんて” has it but I wasn't sure whether “〜など” had. You just answered what I asked actually.